# Does NASA already have James Webb Space Telescope's 1st science photos with them?

Tags: nasa, james-webb-telescope

From this [link](https://www.space.com/james-webb-space-telescope-science-photos-webcast), it clearly says:

> The main image release event will take place on **July 12 at 10:30 a.m. EDT (1430 GMT)**.

Does NASA already have James Webb Space Telescope's 1st science photos with them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does NASA already have James Webb Space Telescope's 1st science photos with them?

Some of them. From the latest (June 23, 2022) [NASA JWST blog post](https://blogs.nasa.gov/webb/2022/06/23/webbs-nirspec-acquires-multiple-targets/),

> The team has started to take some of the first science data, getting it ready to release starting July 12, 2022, which will mark the official end of commissioning Webb and the start of routine science operations.

As of June 24, 2022, NASA has completed commissioning of 12 of the 17 instrument modes. Those commissioned modes are good-to-go. Presumably the July 12, 2022 release event will include imagery / data from all 17 modes.

Comment: I'm not sure, but there might be a lot of post-processing steps, perhaps it could be simultaneously true that the pictures have been taken and that nasa doesn't have the final images yet?

Comment: @0xDBFB7 - I'm sure NASA has some "final" images.  NASA is aware that a $10 billion dollar instrument has a PR mission as well as a science mission, and has carefully planned/is planning how to make a PR splash with the first batch of "operational" images released to the public.

Comment: @antlersoft I'm sure they already have some "final" images as well. The July 12 event inevitably have a bit of dog-and-pony show look-and-feel to them. I wouldn't be surprised if the presentation is close to final form already, perhaps with some holes where missing has to be inserted. It would be downright stupid of NASA to delay things to July 11, or even July 5. Events at this high of a level have reviews and dry runs.