# How long does NASA take to post process JWST images?

Tags: nasa, james-webb-telescope

My question came from this [comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/59551/does-nasa-already-have-james-webb-space-telescopes-1st-science-photos-with-them#comment197320_59553).

How long does NASA take to post process JWST images?